# Can I set the rating bar size to match constraint?

Tags: android, kotlin, constraints, ratingbar

I am finding "solutions" suggesting using the small rating bar style, or to just change the size of the stars with a custom style, but I don't want it to be fixed. I just want the 5 stars bar to match the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexible RatingBar
[FlexibleRatingBar](https://github.com/Amagi82/FlexibleRatingBar)